# Kivy POPUP and Button text

Tags: python, kivy

First I'm new to kivy. myApp is based on `kivy-example/demo/kivycatlog` and I was modifying `PopupContainer.kv`, but my code doesn't work.

**PopupContainer.kv**

```
BoxLayout:
    id: bl
    orientation: "vertical"
    popup: popup.__self__
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .18, .18, .18, .91
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Button:
        id: showPopup1
        text: 'press to show popup'
        on_release: root.popup.open()
    Button:
        id: showPopup2
        text: 'press to show popup'
        on_release: root.popup.open()

Popup:
    id: popup
    on_parent: if self.parent == bl: bl.remove_widget(self)
    title: "An example popup"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                id: accept
                text: "yes"
                on_release: status.text = self.text
            Button:
                id: cancel
                text: "no"
                on_release: status.text = self.text
            Label:
                id: status
                text: "yes or no?"
        Button:
            text: "press to dismiss"
            on_release: popup.dismiss()
```

I want to change the `text(showPopup)` when I click on "yes" or "no"
 on the `showPopup`'s text.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the text of your ShowPopup's buttons from your code. I mean declare a variable in your code named `popups_text` and in your .kv file try accesing it using `root.popups_text`. then create a method in your code that changes this text every time the button is pressed.

Comment: I can't understand where your problem is